# How to alter page content?

Tags: 8, entities

Simple thing. I have some page (node). At end it produces some content, i.e.

```
<h1>This is original content</h1>
```

I want to alter it with different content, i.e.

```
<h1>This is changed content</h1>
```

So I need a way to collect original content, parse it, replace some part of it and put it back.

`hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view()` should be the way to do that:

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view/8.2.x

And I tried example from that page (by Devendra Mishra) and it works, but it's adding additional content. I need a way to access original content and change it, not to just add new one.

To be clear, I don't want to change content on field level, but want to change final content, with all fields combined, ready to be rendered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to change the variables on field level you can parse the content in a #post_render callback after it is rendered:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view().
 */
function mymodule_node_view(array &$build, EntityInterface $entity, EntityViewDisplayInterface $display, $view_mode) { 
  $build['#post_render'][] = function ($html, array $elements) {
    return str_replace('original', 'changed', $html);
  };
}
```

Comment: Works! Thank you very much!

Comment: What? Where's `$html` and `$elements` coming from? 

Comment: @leymannx, see https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/-/blob/8.8.x/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Renderer.php#L496

Comment: What a beautiful pattern!