# How can I replace a string in a text?

Tags: 9

With `{{ content.field_myfield.0 }}`, I get a text. When I use `{{ content.field_myfield.0|replace({"foo" : "bar"}) }}`, nothing is rendered and no errors are reported.

I also tried replacing `content.field_myfield.0` with `content.field_myfield.value` or `content.field_myfield.0.value, but I still get an empty string.

How can I replace a string?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`content.field_some_field` is a render array, but the `replace` filter operates on strings. You need to render your field before calling replace.

For example:

```
{{ content.field_some_field|render|replace({"hello": "goodbye"}) }}
```

Answer (score 6):

If this is a formatted text field you can replace the source text before it is rendered. This has the advantage that HTML tags are preserved:

```
{% set field_item = content.field_myfield.0  %}
{% set text_replaced = field_item['#text']|replace({'foo': 'bar'}) %}
{{ field_item|merge({'#text': text_replaced}) }}
```

If you are not sure about the field type check the render array `{{ dump(field_item) }}`.

You can flatten the render array before replacing, as @sonfd suggested, if the replaced text doesn't contain HTML tags.

In general there are better ways to replace texts. Implement a text filter or a pre_render/post_render callback. See for example https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/module-development-and-code-questions/2020-01-28/creating-a-custom-text-filter or [How to alter page content?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/293517/how-to-alter-page-content)