# Altering paragraph field within revision using preprocess hook

Tags: hooks

I'm using a hook_preprocess function (`hook_preprocess_entity_print`) to alter the content within a paragraph field prior to rendering (replacing some strings based on a regex). This works great when I'm working on the node, but not when I'm trying to do the same on a revision of the node.

This works for the node:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_entity_print().
 */
function mymodule_preprocess_entity_print(&$variables) {
  $route = \Drupal::routeMatch();
  $entity_id = $route->getParameter('entity_id');
  $node = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->load($entity_id);
  $type = $node->getType();
  if ($type === 'product_child') {
    foreach ($node->get('field_submittal_wysiwyg') as $paragraph) {
      $type = $paragraph->entity->getType();
      switch ($type) {
        case 'submittal_2_col':
          $field_submittal_text = $paragraph->entity->field_submittal_text_1->value;
          $field_submittal_text = mymodule_token_replace($field_submittal_text, $variables);
          $paragraph->entity->field_submittal_text_1->value = $field_submittal_text;
          break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I decided to make these same replacements work when rendering a revision of the node, I tried this first:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_entity_print().
 */
function mymodule_preprocess_entity_print(&$variables) {
  $route = \Drupal::routeMatch();
  $entity_id = $route->getParameter('entity_id');
  $revision_id = $route->getParameter('revision_id');
  $node_revision = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->loadRevision($revision_id);
  $type = $node_revision->getType();
  if ($type === 'product_child') {
    foreach ($node_revision->get('field_submittal_wysiwyg') as $paragraph) {
      $type = $paragraph->entity->getType();
      switch ($type) {
        case 'submittal_2_col':
          $field_submittal_text = $paragraph->entity->field_submittal_text_1->value;
          $field_submittal_text = mymodule_token_replace($field_submittal_text, $variables);
          $paragraph->entity->field_submittal_text_1->value = $field_submittal_text;
          break;
      }
    }

  }
}
```

I can confirm that I'm getting the correct values for the draft revision in `$field_submittal_text`. But when I try to set the value of the paragraph, it works only for the published node.

I figured I must not be loading the paragraph revisions referenced within the node revisions. So I then tried to address that:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_entity_print().
 */
function mymodule_preprocess_entity_print(&$variables) {
  $route = \Drupal::routeMatch();
  $entity_id = $route->getParameter('entity_id');
  $revision_id = $route->getParameter('revision_id');
  $node_revision = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->loadRevision($revision_id);
  $type = $node_revision->getType();
  if ($type === 'product_child') {
    $field_submittal_wysiwyg = $node_revision->field_submittal_wysiwyg->referencedEntities();
    foreach ($field_submittal_wysiwyg as $paragraph) {
      $paragraph_type = $paragraph->getType();
      switch ($paragraph_type) {
        case 'submittal_2_col':
          $field_submittal_text = $paragraph->field_submittal_text_1->value;
          $field_submittal_text = mymodule_token_replace($field_submittal_text, $variables);
          $paragraph->field_submittal_text_1->value = $field_submittal_text;
          break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Again, I can confirm that I'm getting the correct values for `$field_submittal_text` based on the revision that I'm trying to load. But the last line before the break isn't changing what is rendered.

What do I need to do to set the value of the paragraph field for a revision before rendering?

ETA: I'm attempting to replace some product attribute values in several paragraph WYSIWYG fields with values from another field, based on a product_id sent in through the route parameters. So I need access to multiple fields in order to do these replacements.

Comment: Doesn't the `$variables` already contain the entity and by that also the parent entity? That means there's no need to get the node from the route. Getting the parent entity from the `$variables` also means your code would work even when you are not viewing a node on its canonical URL (in views for example).

Comment: It's not surprising that I made it more complicated than it needs to be. For some reason, accessing entities programmatically has confused me. Thanks for the advice; I'll look into stripping it down to changing $variables directly.

Comment: So far, in `$variables`, I'm able to find only the published versions of the paragraph fields I'm seeking to alter. I can't locate the draft version. This is the case regardless of whether I'm viewing the published revision or a draft. This is why I went to the extra step of loading the node_revision.

Comment: (I do wonder if I might be missing the values I'm seeking due to a max_depth for my `dump()` statement.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of a preprocess hook is to prepare the variables printed in the template. Check the `{{...}}` statements in the Twig template.

Some other options:

- Look for a different template that prints the variable you want to change.
- Create a custom text filter and add it to the text format.
- Add a #post_render callback, see [How to alter page content?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/293517/how-to-alter-page-content)

Comment: I added a little more context to my question. I'm trying to change some text strings (essentially token strings) in a few paragraph wysiwyg fields with values from another field (product data text field) based on a product_id sent in the route parameters. So I need access to multiple fields at once. All this needs to occur prior to handing over to entity_print to render the PDF. I handled this for the published revision of the node using this preprocess hook; now just trying to make the same thing work for a draft revision.

Comment: Instead of the futile attempt to change objects out of scope in a preprocess hook, you might consider storing the computed data in a new field. The simplest Drupal way for a computed field is an extra field, if you don't want to define a custom field plugin. See https://www.webomelette.com/creating-pseudo-fields-drupal-8. You can also consider putting the extra field inside the paragraph type, it's easier to access the different fields (read-only!) from there.

Comment: I was able to accomplish what I needed with `hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view()`. Thanks!